# DevExpress XtraGrid - how to disable cell merging

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I'm using DevExpress XtraGrid and faced with problem. When cells in under the same column have the same values, they merge in one. But i don't need it. 
Here is printscreen of table:
[image: printscreen of table]

There are two rows. Last two columns have merged. How can i separate these rows???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell merging feature is disabled by default in the GridView. You can disable it directly using the [GridView.OptionsView.AllowCellMerge](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_AllowCellMergetopic). When the View's cell merging mechanism is enabled, you can still prevent cells from being merged for individual columns, if required. Set the desired columns' [OptionsColumn.AllowMerge](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowMergetopic) option to false for this purpose.

Related link: [Cell Merging Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1461)